# Deploying new code doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I've updated my backend code and deployed but something weird happening. It only works in some cases and it looks like not updated.
The updated API works well with Postman and with my local frontend code.
BUT it looks like not updated with the live frontend site.
I think there's a delay to update heroku in all locations.
How to resolve this issue?

I see this error.
[image]

Comment: Caching, maybe? But we can only guess since you haven't provided enough detail to actually diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there is a delay on Heroku, it may be helpful for you to include information like how long you've been waiting. If you've waited longer than five minutes, check your logs.